# $lookup where id fields are of different types

Tags: mongodb, join, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have 2 collections : Transactions & Accounts.

I need to join Accounts to Transactions so I can group on the Accounts.acctType field.  The problem is that Transactions.accountId is of type 'string' and Accounts._id is of type 'Int32'.

is there any way to get around this problem without having to change the Transactions.accountId type?

Current lookup code:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'accounts', 
  localField: accountId, 
  foreignField: '_id', 
  as: 'accountData'
}
```

What I need:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'accounts', 
  localField: Number(accountId), //something like this
  foreignField: '_id', 
  as: 'accountData'
}
```

Or:

```
$lookup: {
  from: 'accounts', 
  localField: accountId, 
  foreignField: '_id.toString()', //or something like this
  as: 'accountData'
}
```

Comment: It is difficult to answer without seeing examples of your data, and understanding how these different fields are supposed to be matchable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making a database change to get the Id field inline with the data type.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) your document and use [`$toLower`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toLower/) to convert the "Transaction" "_id" field to string.

```
db.Transaction.aggregate(
    [
        { "$project": { "_id": { "$toLower": "$_id" } } }, // You need include all the fields you want in your result.
        { "$lookup": {
            "from": "accounts", 
            "localField": "accountId", 
            "foreignField": "_id",
             "as": "accountData"
        }}
    ]
)
```

Comment: Isn't that backwards?  The "_id" field is in the Accounts collection.  I would have to project the Transaction collection casting  "accountId" as a number wouldn't i?

Comment: Is the "_id" of type `int32` in the collection to join?

Comment: Yes the '_id' is int32 in the collection that I want to join.

Comment: @KickinMhl In that case, there is nothing you can do apart from updating the `_id` in one of your collections.